Does Pakistan still have missile cooperation with North Korea?
It is said that Pakistan received significant input into its ballistic missile programs from NK during the 1990s.

Hwasong-7 (Nodong-1)

Is there any indication that suggests that Pakistan is still in cooperation with NK in terms of its own ballistic missile development?
If yes, for what specifically?
If not, why not?

NK seems more advanced these days, so I guess that's an argument against.

Publicly, no more, as Pakistan faces deep economic problems, and economic sanctions against it - for working with North Korea - is the last thing it wants. Especially since it is now common knowledge that Pakistan helped North Korea's nuclear program in exchange for assistance in developing its missile program.
Also, with China now directly assisting Pakistan's missile development program it doesn't need to rely on the North Korean missile program (which was also developed with China's assistance):

Reuters: The U.S. State Department on Thursday imposed sanctions on a Chinese research institute and several companies it said have been involved in supplying Pakistan's ballistic missile program. Washington similarly targeted three China-based companies with sanctions in October 2023 for supplying missile-applicable items to Pakistan.

Some of the missiles developed with China's help include:

The Nasr (Hatf 9) is a Pakistani short-range ballistic missile with a range of 60 – 70 km. Pakistan first revealed the missile in April 2011 as a “quick response” nuclear delivery system. It is derived from China’s WS-2 tactical rocket and was first revealed in April 2011.


The Ghaznavi (Hatf 3) is a Pakistani short-range ballistic missile. It has a range of 300 km and is directly derived from China’s DF-11 short-range ballistic missile.1 Pakistan received significant technical assistance and over 30 DF-11 missiles from China through the early 1990s.


The Shaheen 1 (Hatf 4) is a Pakistani-Chinese short-range ballistic missile. It can launch a payload of 700 – 1,000 kg to ranges of up to 700 km, and its extended-range variant, the Shaheen 1A, ranges up to 900 km. The missile was developed with Chinese technical assistance, and analysts suggest its design may derive from China’s DF-15 system.


The Shaheen 2 (Hatf 6) is a Pakistani medium-range ballistic missile. It appears to be a two-stage version of the Shaheen 1 design, using a modified Shaheen 1 stage as the second stage motor and RV. It is believed that the Shaheen 2 is derived from the People’s Republic of China (PRC)-developed M-18, though this has not been confirmed.

Privately, who knows? No country publicises such covert activities. If they are still working with them, they haven't been caught yet.

Weird this got DV by someone. I don't see anything questionable/objectionable here in terms of facts (+1). Of course, the conclusion for such topics is the eye of the beholder.

According to the Eating Grass book, Pakistan had (at least) two competing missile programs. The Ghauri series was developed by the Khan Research Laboratories, in cooperation with North Korea (whom in return received some centrifuges from Khan), while the Shaheen (and other) missiles were developed in cooperation with China, but by a different Pakistani group (the National Defence Complex and National Engineering & Science Commission.)
The Ghauri series was actually lagging behind the Chinese supported project[s] all along. Due to various external pressures, technology transfers that would have enabled the Ghauri II & III from the North Korean Taepodong (more advanced than the Nodong-1 that Ghauri I was based on) never actually materialized. The Taepodong program of North Korea itself was beset with problems and ultimately only used as technology demonstrators, before being superseded by other designs (confusingly also named Nodong sometimes, like the Nodong-C).
One interesting point however is that North Korea did share further missile tech but with Iran. The Nodong-1 was also the basis of the Iranian Shahab-3, and later the Khorramshahr was apparently based on the Hwasong-10/Musudan/Nodong-B. North Korean designs up to that point were themselves based (directly) on the Soviet ones, rather than the Chinese, e.g. Nodong-1 was basically a Scud derivative, while Soviet R-27 Zyb reportedly was the basis for the Nodong-B.
